# How to gradle build reproducible zip with configurations.runtimeClasspath?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, zip, build.gradle

I have a gradle task to build a reproducible zip, hash it, then I check the hash is the same.

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    preserveFileTimestamps = false
    reproducibleFileOrder = true

    from sourceSets.main.output
}

task createChecksums(type: Checksum, dependsOn: build) {
    inputFiles.setFrom("${buildDir}/distributions");
    appendFileNameToChecksum.set(true)
}
```

This works as expected and the hash is consistent. However I noticed when I try to include the .jar dependencies under `configurations.runtimeClassPath`:

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    preserveFileTimestamps = false
    reproducibleFileOrder = true

    from sourceSets.main.output
    
    into("lib") {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

The hash changes on every clean build. Why is this happening and how to correct it?

Comment: can you compare the contents of two zip archives from different clean builds? e.g. unzip -l <zipfile>. Maybe you can spot a difference in included files / lengths?

Answer (score 3):

It could be possible that the hash changes on every clean build because the order of the files in the **`configurations.runtimeClasspath`** changes. You should try sorting the files in **`configurations.runtimeClasspath`** before adding them to the **zip** to ensure that the order is consistent.

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
includeEmptyDirs = false
preserveFileTimestamps = false
reproducibleFileOrder = true

from sourceSets.main.output 

into("lib") {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.sort()
}
}
```

This should ensure that the order of the files in **`configurations.runtimeClasspath`** is consistent and the hash remains the same on every clean build.